# Why in SDK 30 and later, the background thread of running holder.lockCanvas and holder.unlockCanvasAndPost will still lock UI thread?

Tags: android, android-canvas, kotlin-coroutines, surfaceview

I have a simple SurfaceView that uses Coroutine Dispatcher.Default scope to run on background with code as below

```
override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    doAnimate = true
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        while (doAnimate && isAttachedToWindow) {
            synchronized(holder) {
                val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
                Thread.sleep(500)
                canvas?.let {
                    drawAnimate.draw(it)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine in Android SDK 29 and earlier. I can scroll up and down still without being blocked by the `Sleep` as shown below.

You can get the actual app and code from [here](https://github.com/elye/issue_android_background_sleep_in_lock_canvas_block_uithread/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/elyeproj/surfaceviewexplore/SlowSurfaceView.kt#L42)

[image]

Beginning Android SDK 30 and later, the drawing still working. But seems like the `Sleep` is now blocking the Main.UI Thread and I can no longer scroll smoothly, even though the `Sleep` is behind the coroutine Dispatcher.Default scope (worker thread).

I realize I can work around it by moving the `sleep` outside the `holder.lockCanvas()` and `holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(it)` scope.

```
override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    doAnimate = true
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        while (doAnimate && isAttachedToWindow) {
            synchronized(holder) {
                val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
                canvas?.let {
                    drawAnimate.draw(it)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(it)
                }
                Thread.sleep(500) // <-- Move here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What has changed in Android SDK 30 and later that cause the new behavior? Is this a bug in Android SDK 30 and later or a new restriction?

It does feel like the `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost` scope is now blocking the UI thread. Is that true?

Comment: Response from Reddit this is probably a bug? https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/qtq8jw/is_android_canvas_holderlockcanvas_blocking_ui/hkn09sg/?context=3

Comment: File a bug to Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206249036

Answer (score 2):

Thread.sleep() blocking the thread itself. To delay the coroutine try delay().

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html